# Can it be that some midrashic literature got lost over time?

Tags: talmud-gemara, midrash, mishna

Is it possible that some of the material of the old Jewish midrashim (on the different books of the Hebrew Bible) that was written and was available during the Pre-Talmudic era is no longer available?

Comment: Yes it is. We have many examples of reishonim qouting yerushalmis and medrashim we dont have.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Jose and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Check out the Mekhilta of Rabbi Shimon

Comment: The book of Ben Tagla is a specific lost book, mentioned in Ecclesiastes Rabbah 12:11.

Comment: Much of the Yalkut Shimoni is culled from now lost works.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. One example; is a Midrash known as "Midrash Avkir" (מדרש אבכיר), selections of which are included in Yalkut Shimoni, but is no longer extant in its complete form.

Source: ["Rav Pe'alim", by Rabbi Avraham ben Ha'Gra, p. 27](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14013&st=&pgnum=28)

Comment: Shkoyech. Avkir was the first midrash that came to mind when seeing this question.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Mi Yodeya. The truth is that the material that was lost is probably much more than that which was preserved. One of the editors of the Vilna Shas (referred to as Shafan Hasofer due to his initials) compiled a very extensive list of lost works. It is available online [here.](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45081&st=&pgnum=30&hilite=)